# "IF EXISTS" in PostgreSQL - creating query that updates a record if exists and inserts into if not

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a query "If a record within that second and this sensor_id exists, update it with provided new value, else create a record with that value, sensor_id and time".

I managed to create this query:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT
      1  
   FROM
      public.measurement_pm2_5  
   WHERE
      measurement_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:43', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
      AND    measurement_time <  TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:44', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
      AND    sensor_id = 2
) THEN UPDATE
   public.measurement_pm2_5   
SET
   measurement_value = 27  
WHERE
   measurement_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:43', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
   AND    measurement_time <  TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:44', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
   AND    sensor_id = 2;  
   ELSE INSERT 
   INTO
      public.measurement_pm2_5
      (    sensor_id,    measurement_time,    measurement_value  )  
   VALUES
      (    2,    TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:43', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),    27  );  
   END IF;
END;
$do$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (execution time: 62 ms; total time: 62 ms)
```

Although this query:

```
SELECT
      1  
   FROM
      public.measurement_pm2_5  
   WHERE
      measurement_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:43', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
      AND    measurement_time <  TO_TIMESTAMP('06.07.2016 23:28:44', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
      AND    sensor_id = 2
```

returns one record, the `UPDATE` part of the first query doesn't look to be executed.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

**measurement_pm2_5 table:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.measurement_pm2_5 (
  sensor_id SERIAL,
  measurement_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  measurement_value NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT measurement_pm2_5_sensor_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id)
    REFERENCES public.sensor(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

Comment: What are your datatypes? I tested it with `CREATE TABLE measurement_pm2_5 ( measurement_time timestamp NOT NULL, sensor_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, measurement_value integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ) WITHOUT OIDS;` and it works as expected.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Why do you think that the row was not updated? What client software you are using for test the query? `do` statement does not return any useful information itself (except when error occurred). Just change your `update` statement to `UPDATE  public.measurement_pm2_5 SET measurement_value = measurement_value + 0.01 ...` for example to ensure that all Ok (or not).

Comment: Oh... you're right! It's actually working :D The "SQL Manager Lite for PostgreSQL" is a liar! I feel embarrassed...

Comment: That's the spirit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your SQL code it is easy to tell that you are experienced in procedural programming languages. PL/pgSQL requires a different mindset though. Carefully read [the docs on PL/pgSQL programming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) and start thinking in sets and operations that succeed or fail. This is not at all meant to belittle you; take it as well-intended advice from a fellow programmer who has seen both sides of the fence.

In this case, simply try the `UPDATE` and if it fails, do an `INSERT` instead.

```
DO $do$
DECLARE
    obs timestamp := to_timestamp('06.07.2016 23:28:43', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
BEGIN
    UPDATE public.measurement_pm2_5   
    SET measurement_value = 27  
    WHERE measurement_time = date_trunc('second', obs)
    AND   sensor_id = 2;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN   
        INSERT INTO public.measurement_pm2_5
               (sensor_id, measurement_time, measurement_value)  
        VALUES (2, obs, 27);  
    END IF;
END;
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The query looks much clearer than mine but it still doesn't work. It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. It's weird that `SELECT` (second query in my question) returns a record but the provided query affects 0 rows.